# Using mathnet-numerics as CLR assembly in SQL Server

Tags: sqlclr, math.net

Has anyone successfully used MathNet.Numerics as a CLR assembly in SQL Server?

Using SQL Server 2012 on Windows 8, I've managed to do a CREATE ASSEMBLY pointing at the DLL but when I try to do

```
CREATE TYPE Normal EXTERNAL NAME MathNetNumerics.[MathNet.Numerics.Distributions.Normal]
```

I get an error message:

> "does not conform to the UDT specification: missing custom attribute
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedTYpeAttribute".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you cannot use arbitrary .Net code in SQL CLR but have to develop specifically for it, by decorating your code with attributes like `SqlFunction` and using its own special  types like `SqlDouble` instead of just `System.Double`.

Nevertheless, I'd expect you can write a small wrapper/adapter .Net library and then reference and call Math.NET Numerics routines from there.